# Dealing with multi-dimensional arrays when ndims not known in advance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with data from netcdf files, with multi-dimensional variables, read into numpy arrays. I need to scan all values in all dimensions (axes in numpy) and alter some values. But, I don't know in advance the dimension of any given variable. At runtime I can, of course, get the ndims and shapes of the numpy array.
How can I program a loop thru all values without knowing the number of dimensions, or shapes in advance? If I knew a variable was exactly 2 dimensions, I would do

```
shp=myarray.shape
for i in range(shp[0]):
  for j in range(shp[1]):
    do_something(myarray[i][j])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into `ravel`, `nditer` and `ndindex`.

```
# For the simple case
for value in np.nditer(a):
    do_something_with(value)

# This is similar to above
for value in a.ravel():
    do_something_with(value)

# Or if you need the index
for idx in np.ndindex(a.shape):
    a[idx] = do_something_with(a[idx])
```

On an unrelated note, numpy arrays are indexed `a[i, j]` instead of `a[i][j]`. In python `a[i, j]` is equivalent to indexing with a tuple, ie `a[(i, j)]`.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. I'll be using ndenumerate finally.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) property of numpy arrays, which returns a generator on all values (no matter the shape).

For instance:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> for x in A.flat:
...     print x
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

You can also set the values in the same order they're returned, e.g. like this:

```
>>> A.flat[:] = [x / 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in A.flat]
>>> A
array([[1,  1,  3],
       [2,  5,  3]])
```

I am not sure the order in which `flat` returns the elements is guaranteed in any way (as it iterates through the elements as they are in memory, so depending on your array convention you are *likely* to have it always being the same, unless you are really doing it on purpose, but be careful...)

And this will work for any dimension.

** -- Edit -- **

To clarify what I meant by 'order not guaranteed', the order of elements returned by `flat` does not change, but I think it would be unwise to count on it for things like `row1 = A.flat[:N]`, although it will work most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the easiest with recursion:

```
a = numpy.array(range(30)).reshape(5, 3, 2)

def recursive_do_something(array):
    if len(array.shape) == 1:
        for obj in array:
            do_something(obj)
    else:
        for subarray in array:
            recursive_do_something(subarray)

recursive_do_something(a)
```

In case you want the indices:

```
a = numpy.array(range(30)).reshape(5, 3, 2)

def do_something(x, indices):
    print(indices, x)

def recursive_do_something(array, indices=None):
    indices = indices or []
    if len(array.shape) == 1:
        for obj in array:
            do_something(obj, indices)
    else:
        for i, subarray in enumerate(array):
            recursive_do_something(subarray, indices + [i])

recursive_do_something(a)
```

Comment: If you want both the indices and the values, you can simply use [`ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know numpy had a specific enumerator for ndarray's.

Comment: Nice approach! At first I was sure a recursive would be applicable, but I didn't go into it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Python's itertools module.

- Python 2: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product
- Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

This will allow you to do something along the lines of

```
for lengths in product(shp[0], shp[1], ...):
    do_something(myarray[lengths[0]][lengths[1]]
```